# Better way of checking if the current user already like a post

Tags: performance, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have three models which look like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => :count_post
  has_many :likes
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :likes
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => :count_like
end
```

A user can only like once per Post so I have a method that checks if the current user already like a post and the dislike link is displayed.

```
<% if post.has_like_from? current_user %>
    <li id="like_<%= dom_id(post) %>"><%= link_to "like", create_like_path(:post_id => post.id), :remote => true %></li>
<% else %>
    <li id="dislike_<%= dom_id(post) %>"><%= render 'dislike', :post => post %></li>
<% end %>
```

And I have this method on model post:

```
 def has_like_from?(target_user)
   likes.where(:user_id => target_user.id).first == nil
 end
```

Is there any way to check every post if current user already like a post? I want to increase performance because load to many posts per request.

Example: startrace when load 7 records

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-30 23:32:51 +0700
  ←[1m←[35mUser Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Processing by HomesController#index as HTML
  ←[1m←[36mPost Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY created_at DESC←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mLike Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "likes".* FROM "likes" WHERE "likes"."post_id" = 7 AND "lik
es"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mLike Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "likes".* FROM "likes" WHERE "likes"."post_id" = 6 AND
"likes"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mLike Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "likes".* FROM "likes" WHERE "likes"."post_id" = 5 AND "lik
es"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mLike Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "likes".* FROM "likes" WHERE "likes"."post_id" = 4 AND
"likes"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mLike Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "likes".* FROM "likes" WHERE "likes"."post_id" = 3 AND "lik
es"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mLike Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "likes".* FROM "likes" WHERE "likes"."post_id" = 2 AND
"likes"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mLike Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "likes".* FROM "likes" WHERE "likes"."post_id" = 1 AND "lik
es"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered homes/_posts.html.erb (29.0ms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you created an index for `likes.post_id`? Note also that you can simplify that method by using [has_many](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) with the option `through` and  [ActiveRecord#include?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/include%3F). That's what I'd write (with positive logic, I don't see why `has_like_from?` should perform a `== nil`):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => :count_post
  has_many :likes
  has_many :like_users, :through => :likes

  def liked_by?(user)
    like_users.include?(user)
  end
end
```

Comment: i think this will load whole like_users table to memory, it may be more efficient to do `like_users.exists?(user_id: user.id)`.

Comment: @rui, Here #include? comes from active-record, not Array, it should generate the same SQL than your code. I cannot test right now, but I'd be surprised if that's not the case.